# How to import products along with custom option/ product option in BigCommerce

Tags: import, product, bigcommerce

I have 2 BigCommerce store I want to import all my products along with product options / custom options in CSV format from one store to another store.

I tried to import but the custom options are not import.

Anyone know please help.

Answer (score 1):

Last Row in this table - https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Importing-Products#table

Product's [Custom Fields](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Custom-Fields) => Name of custom field=Name of value;Name of custom field #2=Name of value #2

Eg - **Color=Blue;Material=Cotton**